# Referencing .NET EF6 entities from front end calls

Tags: .net, ajax, entity-framework-6

I am currently working on a .NET web app with EF6 that uses ajax for server calls from the front end. Everything went well but now I need to implement a way to show data of different entities based on which one the client chooses. I would like to avoid using raw SQL queries.

I have tried passing the name of an entity and using the following code to get the content of the entity by its string name:

```
typeof([EntitiesClass]).GetProperty([EntityNameAsString]).GetValue([ObjectOfEntitiesClass], null);
```

..but I don't have a good feeling about this as I am struggling to work with it getting column names etc.

Do you have any suggestions or link where I could observe how ppl do refer to the EF6 entities from front end?

Comment: Maybe Breeze can help you out here.